# Django tutorial: NameError: global name 'datetime' is not defined

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm following this Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial05/

When I run `python manage.py test polls`, I get this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_was_published_recently_with_future_question (polls.tests.QuestionModelTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/learning-django/mysite/polls/tests.py", line 18, in test_was_published_recently_with_future_question
    self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
  File "/home/user/learning-django/mysite/polls/models.py", line 16, in was_published_recently
    return self.pubDate >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
NameError: global name 'datetime' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

This is my `tests.py` code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Question

import datetime

class QuestionModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() returns `False`for questions whose pubDate is in the future
        """
        time=           timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question=Question(pubDate=time)
        self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
```

Why does Django/Python keep giving me this error even when I have `import datetime` in `tests.py`?

Comment: `tests.py` imports `datetime`, but that's not the file the NameError is coming from. Look at `models.py`.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this on top of file **models.py**:

```
import datetime
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call not just datetime(since it's a folder), but **datetime.datetime** in your current code

or replace the import to

```
 from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.timedelta(days=30)` gives the error `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'`. If I replace `import datetime` with `from datetime import datetime`, I get the same error.

Comment: try from datetime import timedelta. You can also find more info here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html